# Need Help Decoding Unix Time Stamp Into a Date(Discord)

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, discord.py

Basically I need help with decoding a Unix code.
The variable that stores the Unix code is `playerlog1`

I've tried this code,and others but my lack of understanding of this makes it hard to implement into my own code

```
import datetime
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1500000000)
print(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Basically I have a Unix code that prints numbers, and not the actual date which I want to fix

```
import discord
import os
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='1')
num = 1
Error = 'Error Please Try Again'

def getinfo(call):
    req = requests.get(call)
    return req.json()
```

## where my problem is ⬇

```
@bot.command()
async def displayembed(ctx):
    uuid = "uuid"
    apikey = 'key'
    url = f'https://api.hypixel.net/player?key={apikey}&uuid={uuid}'
    urldata = getinfo(url)
    playername1 = urldata["player"]["playername"]
    playerlog1 = urldata["player"]["lastLogout"]
    squishemb = discord.Embed(title='Info', discription='this is info about redacted', colour=discord.Colour.purple())
    squishemb.add_field(name='Player Name', value=playername1, inline=True)
    squishemb.add_field(name='Logout', value=playerlog1, inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=squishemb)

TOKEN = "redacted"
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Edit:
Okay I figured it out,I needed to do what abosr told me then I divided the variable by 1000

```
playerlog1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(urldata["player"]["lastLogout"]/1000)
```

Comment: new code: urldata = getinfo(url)
    playername1 = urldata["player"]["playername"]
    playerlog1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(urldata["player"]["lastLogout"])
    squishemb = discord.Embed(title='Info', discription='this is info about redacted', colour=discord.Colour.purple())
    squishemb.add_field(name='Player Name', value=playername1, inline=True)
    squishemb.add_field(name='Logout', value=playerlog1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), inline=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you would first want to change unix timestamp to python datetime (using your own example:

```py
playerlog1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(urldata["player"]["lastLogout"])
```

and then use that formatted to what ever format you need:

```py
squishemb.add_field(name='Logout', value=playerlog1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), inline=True)
```

The `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` string can be changed for a different display of the date and time, that one formats something like `2021-06-26 12:01:02`.

Comment: Thanks Absor for responding fast.I did what you told me but i got a error           
 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: I tinkered around a little and I kinda got somewhere but now it shows this:                   'line 22, in displayembed
    playerlog1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(urldata["player"]["lastLogout"])
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument'